# What's the maximum Directive Score a player can have?

Tags: planetside-2

Recently in Planetside 2, the [Directives system was added in the July 2014 update](https://forums.station.sony.com/ps2/index.php?threads/directives.196013/). With this system in place, players can earn points (Directive Score) for completing tiers of Directives under the three categories of "Infantry", "Vehicles", and "Weapons". There are usually four tiers for each of the Directives (Novice, Adept, Expert, and Master).

My question is the following: what is the maximum Directive Score that a player can attain by completing all the tiers of every directive?

Comment: Hey, Marvon.  I've removed the data specific information from your question.  That's so that even in a year or two (or more), your answers can still be applicable.  We won't need a new question every time they change the directives system, just an updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of December 5, 2014: There are 29 directive categories (not including events) which give a total of 140 directive points each when completed at the Auraxium level. That means the maximum is 4060 directive points per character, not including seasonal events.

Note that since directive score is shared for all characters per account, and accounts have 3 character slots by default (or 6 with membership) with additional slots available for purchase, the maximum directive score for an account is 12,180 for free users and potentially unlimited for paid users who purchase additional character slots.

Comment: Wow, so that means if I were to create a new character with the same faction as my old one, I could still get more directive score by re-completing objectives on my new character.

Comment: In theory yes, but there are so many more fun things to do in PS2 than grind directives :D

Comment: Ah very well. That answers my question then. Thanks!